# Velocity based motion model (dead reckoning)

Tags: ekf, motion

I'm trying to understand the derivation of the velocity based motion model to implement an EKF:
[image]

But the problem is, that I cannot find any derivation/explanation. Mostly there is only a visualization of the odometry based model.
What are some useful references?

Answer (score 0):

I did basically this for my last job. I also am not going to be able to cite any sources here on this, but if you consider a state feedback controller you have a state vector $\vec{x}$, state matrix $A$, an input $u$ and an input vector $\vec{B}$.

You can extend your state vector to include a *bias* term. For a rotational system you would expect to have the rotational equivalent of

$$
F = ma \\
$$

which is

$$
\tau = J\alpha \\
$$

If you were modeling this system such that you have torque as an input and angular position $\theta$ as an output then you would probably do something like:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
\dot{\theta} \\
\ddot{\theta}\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}
\theta \\
\dot{\theta} \end{matrix}\right] + \left[\begin{matrix}
0 \\
\frac{1}{J}\end{matrix}\right]u
$$

I'll use the symbol gamm $\gamma$ for bias torque because that's what you have in your graphic. If you assume a constant bias, then what you're saying is that you're assuming $\dot{\gamma} = 0$, and so you can extend your equation:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
\dot{\theta} \\
\ddot{\theta} \\
\dot{\gamma}\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{J} \\
0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}
\theta \\
\dot{\theta} \\
\gamma \end{matrix}\right] + \left[\begin{matrix}
0 \\
\frac{1}{J} \\
0\end{matrix}\right]u
$$

This may look like it's a trivial addition, but now your bias term $\gamma$ affects your angular acceleration:

$$
\ddot{\theta} = \frac{1}{J}\left(u + \gamma\right) \\
$$

and a Kalman filter will actual estimate this bias term for you. I used this kind of extension for a very challenging problem and was able to successfully estimate wind forces. No anemometer, I could estimate just by how the motion of the system deviated from what I expected.